# Is "iff" considered a real word or just an abbreviation?

Tags: pronouns, abbreviations, mathematics, dictionaries, is-it-a-word

I wonder if **"iff"** is considered a real word (as [LEO](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&p=DOKJAA&search=iff&trestr=0x2008) says) or is it just an abbreviation (as in [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iff))?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with [today's XKCD](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/formal_logic.png)?

Comment: @Jim Yes. You got me.

Comment: It’s considered an abomination. [If you find that writing “if and only if” is too long, use the proper symbol, i.e. “↔”]

Comment: @Konrad: For those writing metalogical statements, "↔", "⇔", and "iff" work at different levels and all three are needed. "A ↔ B ⇔ ((A ∧ B) ∨ ~(A ∨ B)) iff our definitions follow standard propositional semantics." ↔ is used as a truth function, ⇔ is used as equivalence, and iff is used to explain the conditions when the equivalence holds.

Comment: @Joe … or use parentheses. But I get the example. It’s indeed useful here. Still, I’d prefer the long form then.

Comment: Parentheses disambiguate order, not meaning. The full parenthesized form "(A ↔ B) ↔ ((A ∧ B) ∨ ~(A ∨ B))" is a single sentence in propositional logic. "A ↔ B ⇔ ((A ∧ B) ∨ ~(A ∨ B))" is a statement _about_ two sentences in prop. logic. You might be able to get away with nested quoting, but it wouldn't be nearly as clear.

Comment: @Konrad, specifically who considers it an abomination? That's a strong statement, and I think there are many, many people who would disagree. Are you referring specifically to usage outside of mathematics?

Comment: @amcnabb Me. ;-)

Comment: @Joe I’m not an expert but it’s my understanding that the parenthesised form, while certainly less readable, is strictly equivalent to the form using two different operators. In both cases you are stating an equivalence relation between an equivalence relation and a disjunction. I don’t think there’s a formal distinction between “truth function” and “equivalence” – as you use them – in this context.

Comment: I never use 'iff'. It's rare to have a situation where the distinction between 'if' and 'if-and-only-if' is important enough to make, but not important enough to guard against people being unfamiliar with the abbreviation.

Comment: +1 for referring to XKCD. I always wondered if **"neccesary and sufficient"** (a phrasing of iff) will have the **same** meaning in a mainstream context. The iff thing would have a tougher time reaching mainstream.

Comment: @Konrad: No, you're just wrong. They _mean different things_. "(A ∧ B) ↔ (B ∧ A)" is a single logical statement. It is true or false (usually true). "(A ∧ B) ⇔ (B ∧ A)" or "(A ∧ B) iff (B ∧ A)" is a statement in a higher-level language _about two logical statements_. It is introduced definitionally, or axiomatically, or to summarize a sequences of transformations comprising a proof, etc. I don't know what your crusade against "iff" is about, but it's apparently not based on actually having done much mathematical/philosophical logic.

Comment: @Joe My “crusade” against “iff” is entirely about it being an (IMHO) useless and gratuitous abbreviation (\*), not semantically motivated. Thanks for the clarification; I was indeed unaware that these two levels differ. FWIW I *do* have some basic education in logic but it’s been a long time ago and I haven’t ever used more than the essentials that are necessary for Computer Science. (*) How ironic, given my pervasive use of abbreviations in this answer. ;-)

Comment: Here is the link to the discussion of "iff" in the Mathematics Stack Exchange website: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39022/alternative-ways-to-say-if-and-only-if

Comment: @MBober, This is like asking is "real estate" a real word or a legal term. Or whether "exculpatory" and "inculpatory" are real words or legal terms. Or whether "phenomena" and "noumena" are real words or science terms.

Comment: Classifying something one way or another is important when something depends on it. Does anything depend on whether *iff* is classified as a 'real word' or an abbreviation?

Comment: On the history of the word ... https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/7048/229

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I would count it as jargon and I'd never use it in prose. It's a programming/maths term meaning *if and only if* and should be restricted to circles where it's likely to be understood (**edit** like [XKCD](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/formal_logic.png) ).

The question of whether it's an abbreviation is interesting. It's obviously shorter than "if and only if" but I think I'd say it was a more of a symbol. Perhaps that's my programming background coming out [where *symbol* has a particular meaning ([see number 2 here](https://chambers.co.uk/search/?query=Symbol&title=21st))]. However as it consists of more than one recognisable letter, it might be better to say it's an abbreviation

[Here's an Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=iff%2Cif+and+only+if&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) which shows that *iff* has become more popular recently, corresponding to the increase in  computing. That may explain the increase in "if and only if" as well. I have no idea whether the incidence around 1800 is simply an alternative spelling of *if* or whether that actually meant "if and only if".

Comment: It is not (only) a programming term, however. More of a logic term, I would say.

Comment: You're right, as today's XKCD indicates. But I'm not an expert in formal logic. And not an expert programmer either(!) but that's where my experience lies.

Comment: @Eyvind More a *maths and* logic term. Often used in mathematical proofs (often the proof is to prove the "iff" in a statement).

Comment: Maths, logics and programmings alike. @Richard. ;-)

Comment: Philosophy, math, CS, ling, engin, they all use it. But never in speech. There is no special pronunciation difference between _iff_ and _if_, so it couldn't be used in speech. It's strictly in informal writing (handouts, blackboard, notes, blogs, letters, etc.)

Comment: @JohnLawler Actually there is an important (*critical*) distinction in how `if` and `iff` are pronounced: `if` is pronounced "if", and `iff` is pronounced "if *and only if*" - In the context of formal logic they have substantially different meanings. `iff` is a generally accepted abbreviation in the Mathematics and Computer Science fields (and probably others that invoke formal logic), but it is definitely an abbreviation/shorthand, not a word.

Comment: I had only heard it in military aviation. IFF = "Identify Friend Foe" is a radio transponder that stops you shooting your own side.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, Link http://www.chambersharrap.co.uk/chambers/features/chref/chref.py/main?query=symbol 404.

Comment: @Richard, Well, maths uses logic, and programming uses logic, so it's a logic term.

Comment: I've heard some colleagues mention the word [iff] was actually introduced with the intentions of using it to replace the [if] one saw in mathematical definitions. Apparently, some students didn't notice the differences of usage of [if] when it was in a theorem versus a definition (where in the later case it denoted an equivalence or an [if and only if]). It doesn't seem that people intended it to replace the [if and only if] one saw in theorems though. Unfortunately I can't find a citation to back this up. But some math usage arises on some blackboard and the origin story is forgotten.

Comment: I think it's worth adding to this accurate account of 'iff' that it is used as one of three entailment relations.  1) 'P is true if Q is true', (i.e. if Q is true, then P must also be true.  So if Q is true, P must also be true.  BUT IF Q IS UNTRUE, THAT DOES NOT ENTAIL THAT P MUST BE TRUE.   2) 'P is true ONLY if Q', meaning 'if Q is untrue, then P must also be untrue'. In that case, if Q is true, that entails nothing about the truth or falsity of P.  3) 'P is true if and only if ["iff"] Q' .  This latter is equivalent to saying that P and Q are LOGICALLY EQUIVALENT.

Answer (score 14):

While acknowledging the excellent answer from @Andrew Leach, one man's jargon is another man's specialized terminology. To the non-mathematician, this is jargon. To the logician, this is an abbreviation that is used in a similar way (though not as frequently) as QED. (At the bottom of a proof, a mathematician will write QED, standing for *quod erat demonstrandum*, to indicate that he or she has proven that which was set out to be proven.) 
You may find QED in popular usage, but it is both specialized terminology and an abbreviation.

I first ran across *IFF* in my 8th grade algebra class, and it was used in logic truth tables. It meant, as others have correctly stated, "If-and-only-if."

In the context of the XKCD comic, it means Honk if (and only if) you love formal logic. The truth table would be:

```
You love              You honk           You obey the 
formal logic                             bumper sticker
Yes                   Yes                Yes
No                    No                 Yes
Yes                   No                 No
No                    Yes                No
```

This means that if you honk because the driver swerved into your lane, then you are not obeying the bumper sticker (or the truth value of the bumper sticker's logical statement). And if you don't honk even though you love formal logic, then you're not obeying the truth value of the bumper sticker.

My experience in both programming and math has seen IFF rarely in programming and sometimes in math and logic. Few programmers, for instance, would recognize the equivalence between ~ XOR (not Exclusive OR operation) and IFF.

Q.E.D., but IFF you understood the truth table.

Comment: +1 This is a great explanation of _iff_, although it's not good driving advice at all.

Comment: Also, writing Q.E.D. at the end of proofs is a bit unfashionable these days. The current fashion is to draw a little black box, sometimes called a 'tombstone'.

Comment: My profs would sometimes use the "Therefore" sign (U+2234 or ∴) at a conclusion, and in place of QED; this was more for lemmas than proofs. I will not dispute "unfashionable." My exposure to QED and IFF were back in the day when "high tech" meant a K&E slide rule or a four-function calculator.

Answer (score 6):

OED 1971 doesn't list iff at all.  The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition says it's an abbreviation.  Difficult to consider it a real word when it's normally pronounced as three separate letters.

Comment: Oh, and the New Zealand Oxford Dictionary (2005) lists iff, but doesn't label it as an abbreviation.  In my opinion, it's wrong not to do so.

Comment: The online version of the OED has it and defines it as "A written form of abbreviation of the phrase ‘if and only if’, always read as ‘if and only if’, used in Math. and Logic to introduce a condition that is necessary as well as sufficient, or a statement that is implied by and implies the preceding one.'"

Comment: It's normally pronounced as for different words.

Comment: @Hugo, that's like saying USA is normally pronounced "United States of America". You can say "I F F" or you can say "if and only if"; but if you say "if and only if", then you're not pronouncing "iff". When I studied mathematics, my lecturers would normally pronounce it "I F F", despite the blanket statement by the OED that this never happens.

Comment: Fair enough then. When I studied logic, the lecturers always said "if and only if". They only said "I. F. F." when introducing the notation for the first time.

Comment: @David: in my experience, this abbreviation is pronounced "if and only if" in the same way *etc* is pronounced "et cetera".  That in your experience it's pronounced "I F F" is interesting, but doesn't make one more valid than the other.

Comment: @TimLymington Good point, I hadn't thought of etc and others like it.  Perhaps my comment to Hugo was unjustified.

Comment: Maybe some math abbreviations (like xor) should be considered real words. But if you can't pronounce it, it's an abbreviation.

Comment: My dictionary lists it as a conjunction.  And gives the pronunciation "if".

Comment: @GEdgar: I don't think I've heard any mathematicians pronounce it "if"; in my experience, it's usually pronounced "if and only if" and occasionally "eye eff eff".

Comment: *iff*: "First published in A Supplement to the OED II, 1976."  Classified as a *noun*.

Comment: @GEdgar - The noun form is in the online OED as well, but listed as an abbreviation, *not* a word.

Comment: @PeterShor: I would pronounce "iff" as two syllables: "i-ff", with a break between.

Comment: In my experience, _IFF_ pronounced "eye eff eff" is a military system, and _iff_ in the context of logic is pronounced "if and only if."

Answer (score 4):

Re: is *iff* a word, or an abbreviation?

Does it need to be one or the other?  It doesn't seem to be either one, in a pure sense.

I'm more comfortable identifying it as *shorthand* for "if and only if".

Dictionaries specifically relate the word *shorthand* to the standardized system of stenography, but many also list a secondary definition, something along the lines of "an abbreviated or shortened way of communicating something."

Wear the shoe iff it fits... In this case, I think *shorthand* fits better than either *abbreviation* or *word*.

Answer (score 2):

Although I had expected recent dictionaries to agree unanimously that *iff* is primarily an abbreviation, I found that is not the case. On the one hand (consistent with user16269's answer from 2012), *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fifth edition (2011) has this entry for (lowercase) *iff*:

> **iff** *abbr.* if and only if

*AHDEL* also has an entry for uppercase *IFF*:

> **IFF** *abbr.* identification, friend or foe

So *AHDEL* and the *OED* (as reported in Greybeard's recent answer) assert that *iff* is to be understood fundamentally as an abbreviation.

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003), however, takes a different view. Here are its entries for *iff* and *IFF*:

> **iff** *conj* \ˈif-ᵊn(d)-ˈōn-lē-ˌif; ˈif, *sometimes read with a prolonged* f\ *conj* {alter. of [conjunctive] *if*} (1955) : if and only if <two figures are congruent *iff* one can be placed over the other so that they coincide>

> **IFF** *abbr* identification, friend or foe

In its "Explanatory Notes" section, the *Eleventh Collegiate* remarks that its functional labels are not limited to traditional parts of speech:

> Other italicized labels used to indicate functional classifications that are not traditional parts of speech are: **geog** *abbr* [other labels omitted]

To the untrained eye (mine), MW's treatment of abbreviated forms appears to be unpredictably arbitrary. For example, it identifies *SUV* as a noun (equivalent to *sports utility vehicle*) but categorizes *SVGA* as an "abbr" (for "super video graphics array"); and it identifies SWAK" as an "abbr" (for "sealed with a kiss") but treats *WYSIWIG* as a noun (based on "what you see is what you get," but with a distinct nominal meaning). The consistent logic underlying these various decisions is difficult to discern.

Incidentally, *MW*'s first occurrence date of 1955 for *iff* in the relevant sense is subject to revision. Multiple Google Books sources attribute the short form of the expression to the mathematician Paul Halmos, although I haven't found a source that identifies the particular text in which he introduced it. The notation certainly goes back at least to 1950. From William Feller, [*An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ot8IAQAAIAAJ&q=%22iff%22+%22if+and+only+if%22&dq=%22iff%22+%22if+and+only+if%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiX6dfavvP_AhU-AjQIHZz8CCwQ6AF6BAgFEAI), volume 2 (1950):

> *Iff* is an abbreviation for *if and only if*.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't really care if it's listed or not.

IFF is, as far as I know, an established contraction of ***if and only if*** in engineering, physics,  philosophy (*I believe the first experience I had with IFF was when our philosophy professor used it*), and as I recall in mathematics as well. Some people are snarky about it, some aren't. I use it all the time. I've seen it used in all the areas above over the past three or four decades.

Perhaps not definitively a "word" in the spoken sense. but a "working" word or defacto written word? Yes, pretty much.

Answer (score 0):

"Iff" is  classed an abbreviation by OED

> **A written form of abbreviation of the phrase ‘if and only if’, always read as ‘if and only if’, used in Mathematics and Logic to introduce a condition that is necessary as well as sufficient, or a statement that is implied by and implies the preceding one.**
>
> 1955   J. L. Kelley Gen. Topol. vii. 232   *F is equicontinuous at x iff there is a neighborhood of x whose image under every member of F is small.*
>
> 1971   G. Hunter Metalogic 16   *Hereafter we abbreviate ‘if and only if’ to ‘iff’.*
>
> 1972   Royal Inst. Philos. Lect. V. 34   *An integer n is prime iff the only integers which divide it without remainder are itself and one.*

However, it operates as a preposition.