# Pronunciation of iff

Tags: pronunciation, abbreviations

Do most of English speakers understand the word "iff" in text, and is there a standard pronunciation other than the full "if and only if"?

Comment: Related: *[Is “iff” considered a real word or just an abbreviation?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62067)*

Comment: Note that it would be inappropriate to use "iff" in ordinary text.  It should only be used in the context of formal logic, etc.  If writing, say, an article about baseball you should not say "The Mets will be contenders iff Joe Schmoe can get off his duff", but should spell it out.

Comment: It's not uncommon for jargon to be optimised for written communication, so in a sense we have a word in writing but an abbreviation for a phrase in speech. And abbreviations that are likely to lead to ambiguity in context are generally expanded when spoken.

Comment: To this native American English speaker, who has no training in logic, "iff" looks like a misspelling of "if".  And my spell-check agrees.  But apparently, it's in the online dictionaries.  Merriam-Webster gives its pronunciation as "if and only if" (in spite of its three-letter spelling), while Oxford and Collins just pronounce it "if".  So I'd say don't use this questionable form in ordinary language, especially orally, unless you want to confuse people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the occurrence of the term is any indication of common understanding, then it would appear by Google's word statistics that the word is somewhat known, although probably not by everyone. According to [their numbers](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=7&case_insensitive=on&content=iff), "iff" had a prevalence of ~0.0000853% in 2008, which was more than "kanguru" (~0.0000000411%) but less than "veracity" (~0.000150%). Nevertheless, how commonly a word is used is probably not a good indication of how well known it is. I personally know the term "iff", but I do not suspect that it is very well known overall. The only way I would pronounce it is as the full "if and only if".

Answer (score 3):

When I was working with formal logic in an academic setting, [iff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) was pronounced as if it were a symbol: "if and only if".

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, "iff" has always been read as "if and only iff." Since otherwise the "iff" would be audibly similar to "if" when read aloud as it looks, I wouldn't recommend it.