# Is it proper to use iff to denote if and only if in academic writing (papers)?

Tags: writing, academia

if and only if (shortened iff) is a biconditional logical connective between statements. Is it proper to use iff to denote if and only if in academic writing (papers)?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You may find the answer to this question in *[Is “iff” considered a real word or just an abbreviation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62067)*; if (but not only if) you do not, I would encourage you to [edit] the post to explain why, so that this question does not get reported as a duplicate. Note that while *iff* might be widely used among academicians in philosophy or mathematics, I would suspect it to be less so among their counterparts in, say, dramaturgy or ethnomusicology; in other words, "academic writing" may be too broad to provide a definitive answer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer will vary from journal to journal. I suggest you browse those journals you respect most and imitate them. Broadly speaking, yes, as an abbreviation many journals will allow abbreviations if they are used over and over again; in such cases, the purpose is to ease the burden of readers.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using it within a logical expression, then yes. If you're using it as an abbreviation in standard prose, then no.

Comment: (1+) I have up-voted your answer on the condition (if and only if) that you add a citation to prove that this is not just your own opinion.

Comment: Whereas I've downvoted. Absolute statements such as these are almost never true.